# Issues Configuring CLion, Cmake, and SFML

Tags: cmake, sfml, clion

I am currently trying to configure my Cmake file to include the SFML libraries.
My CMakeLists.txt. I'm using OS X Yosemite if that matter at all.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(SFMLTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -stdlib=lib++")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(SFMLTest ${SOURCE_FILES})

#Detect and add SFML
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Users/Home/SFML-2.2-osx-clang-universal/cmake/Modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
find_package(SFML 2.2 REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)
if (SFML_FOUND)
    include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(${main.cpp} ${SFML_Libraries})
endif()
```

and the error I am currently getting is

```
Error:By not providing "FindSFML.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked 
CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "SFML", but CMake did notfind one.
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "SFML" (requested version 2.2) 
with any of the following names:
 SFMLConfig.cmake   sfml-config.cmake
Add the installation prefix of "SFML" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or 
set "SFML_DIR"to a directory containing one of the above files.  
If "SFML" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

my FindSFML.cmake is located at

```
/Users/Home/SFML-2.2-osx-clang-universal/cmake/Modules
```

Comment: What is the *exact* name of your file on disk? You said "my findSFML.cmake is ..." CMake is looking for `FindSFML.cmake`. Notice the case difference. And why are you prefixing the path with `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}`?

Comment: Angew, It is FindSFML.cmake that was a typo on my part, I found this solution on an old post on SO, but It didn't help in the way they said it would...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question says the full path to the find module is

```
/Users/Home/SFML-2.2-osx-clang-universal/cmake/Modules/FindSFML.cmake
```

But you're adding `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Users/Home/SFML-2.2-osx-clang-universal/cmake/Modules` to your `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`. `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` is the absolute path to the directory containing the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file. If you know the absolute path to the module file you want to include, you should most certainly not prefix it with the source tree path. Just change the line to this:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "/Users/Home/SFML-2.2-osx-clang-universal/cmake/Modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
```

Also note that since you have `REQUIRED` specified among the arguments to `find_package()`, CMake will terminate with an error if the package cannot be found. Having `if(SFML_FOUND)` is therefore pointless.

Comment: @David: Would you mind to accept the answer? Otherwise the question looks like it has not been answered.

Answer (score -1):

This solution is perfect: https://oxymeos.shost.ca/article.php?about=work_with_the_SFML_in_CLion. I recommend it! It worked for me

You create a folder named "cmake_modules" at the root of the project and you place in this folder the "FindSFML.cmake" file (on Windows and Mac OS X: "[Your_SFML Location]/cmake/Modules/FindSFML.cmake", and on Linux: "[Your_SFML_location]/share/SFML/cmake/Modules/FindSFML.cmake".

The CMake configuration file (CMakeLists.txt) is then presented in this form:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project([your_project])

# Define the source and the executable
set(EXECUTABLE_NAME "[name_executable]")
add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} [project_files])


# Detect and add SFML
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
find_package(SFML 2 REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)
if(SFML_FOUND)
    include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```